# How to apply layer style to one object and apply it to multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style, smartobject

I think what I may be looking for exists in Fireworks maybe, but I haven't messed with it.
Basically, is there a way to make a style sheet for an object?

Say I have an object and I apply x layer styles to it, then I want all those layer styles on multiple objects throughout a document. Then I want to change the strength of a drop shadow, how would I set it up so all I had to do is change the drop on the master file and it would apply to all with this "style" set on it?

Comment: You can convert one or more layers into a smart object. If you duplicate Smart object and go to edit the contents of one of those Smart objects, all the copies of it will be updated with the changes.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to:

- Create the layer
- Add the styles you want
- Right click the layer and select `Copy Layer Styles`
- Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd> and select the other layers you want to add the styles to
- Right click one and `Paste Layer Styles`.

Comment: Thanks -- this was exactly what I needed to apply the same border styles to a set of concentric circles.

Answer (score 7):

This is now somewhat possible with Photoshop CS6 or newer.

You can place all the layers you wish to apply the style to into a Layer Group. Then apply the layer style directly to the group.

[image: drop shadow]

Answer (score 3):

A more effective way to copy/paste layer style is to set up shortcuts.

Edit > Keyboard shortcuts > Application menu > Layer >

> Set up shortcuts:
>   Copy Layer Style –  <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
>   Paste Layer Style –  <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
>   Clear Layer Style – <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Select layer in layers panel and press <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
Select other layers and press <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Hint: 
you can set up a shortcut for 'blending options' too, but it's better to set up 'Drop shadow' shortcut or other option that you use often, than 'blending options'.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has layer styles you can create and apply via the layer styles panel.

Initially when creating a style for a layer, at the bottom of the layers panel, click the little 'fx' button. (Add your drop shadows etc there on a per layer basis) You can create styles in there and manage them under the styles tab.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. I think you have to manually select all when reapplying a style. To my knowledge there isn't a way to auto update them all without reapplying.